# php virtual directory based on session variable and database queries

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

In my website, I've three type of users, let's say A, B and C. The webpages accessible to them are mostly different, but still few overlap. And I've made the directory as follows. Like.

```
Root
    A
        A1
        A2
        A3
        K1
        K2
    B
        B1
        B2
        K1
    C
        C1
        C2
        C3
        K1
        K2
```

So here files K1 and K2 have common names, though not similar content. When A type of user logins, he can browse through `domain.com/A/A1/` `domain.com/A/K2/` etc. B type of user can browse through `domain.com/B/B1` and so on.

What I want it, that when A type of user logins, he browses through `domain.com/A1/` `domain.com/K1` etc. and so on, without using the `A` `B` etc in between. Now to prevent the clearness of the files, I cannot mingle all the files together, and so need to keep them in same directory configuration as describes above. So how to do? What to do?

mod_rewrite helps in creating virtual directories but it shall not help in this case as we need PHP session variables n databse queries to select how to show, and what all to keep accessible to user.

I may not be much clear, so please ask for any issues you get while understanding the question.
Thanks.

Comment: Where is the "type of user" stored? In a session cookie? In a database of active sessions? A query string parameter?

Comment: Session variable stores the UID of the user and based on the UID we may know the type of the user by querying from a group table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do 2 things: get the requested URI, get the User Type. Then you will know what directory to serve. htaccess and mod_rewrite is insufficient in doing the second thing since it has no access to a database.

What you can do is route everything into some sort of php controller using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /user_type.php?request=$1 [L]
```

The `user_type.php` will then know the first thing from the `request` `$_GET` variable, and it can then do the second thing by fetching the user type, then return the request based on the user type. Something like:

```
$file_to_serve = $_GET['request'];

if($user_type == 'A')
    $file_to_serve = 'A/' . $file_to_serve;
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know that .htaccess can fetch a php script. How to send back to .htaccess? `return $file_to_serve;` ?

Comment: I shall check out tomorrow myself. Late night here now.

Comment: @k_programmer don't need to send it back to htaccess, the php script would simply output the contents of `$file_to_serve` and the browser renders it.

Comment: Well I tried this code. There was no output rendered by the browser, so I added `include($file_to_serve);` but now I'm getting 403 forbidden.
`failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\wintern\user_type.php on line 16`

Comment: @k_programmer You may need to include in the path `C:\\wamp\\www\\wintern\\` to the beginning of `$file_to_serve`

Comment: Same error with `C:\\wamp\\www\\wintern\ ` or `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` . Anything else you would suggest?

Comment: Saw the code after days, and found the error. I was including the directory instead of the file. Just appended `.'index.php'` after `$file_to_serve` for the directories, which solved the problem :)